# Get Image Position in iphone application

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, uitouch

I like to get the position ie. xposition and yposition of an image in my code. How to extract the positions. Can some one guide me.

Answer (score 2):

`CGPoint pos = view.center`